# How/Where to override method defined in ActiveSupport CoreExtensions String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I want to override the behavior of ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::String::Inflections.foreign_key in Rails 3 not sure where how to do it properly.

In Rails 2.3 I created a plugin that opened the class and redefined the method but it does not seem to work in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::String::Inflections#foreign_key` delegates to `ActiveSupport::Inflector.foreign_key` where the actual logic is, so I'd suggest patching the latter.

Try putting this to `config/initializers/extensions.rb`:

```
require 'inflector_extensions'
```

Then your code goes into `lib/inflector_extensions`:

```
module ActiveSupport::Inflector
  def foreign_key(class_name, separate_class_name_and_id_with_underscore = true)
    underscore(demodulize(class_name)) + '_my_legacy_suffix'
  end
end
```

This should give:

```
$ ./script/rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.11)
>> "whetever".foreign_key
=> "whetever_my_legacy_suffix"
```